# Cordova/Phonegap-iOS: iPad Icon Requirement Error in Application Loader

Tags: ios, cordova, icons

I'm using Cordova 1.7. I'm about to submit the app but I have this error:

```
iPad: icon.png: icon dimensions (57x57) don't meet the size requirements. The icon file must be 72x72 pixels in .png format.
```

Ever came across this error before with Cordova/Phonegap? How did you solve this issue?

Comment: Where is the error coming from ? When you build in Xcode or are you using build.phonegap.com ?

Comment: @AdamWare I have the exact same problem and I'm using Cordova on XCode.

Comment: I followed the instructions of user1394625 instructions , the error went away.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue...so I checked the previous versions of my app-Info.plist file from the Phonegap era.

Turns out the new Cordova app-Info.plist file uses the "Icon files (iOS 5)" key in the plist file. Phonegap used to use the "Icon files" key...no "(iOS 5)" at the end of it

So the simple solution is to create/add a "Icon files" key in your app-Info.plist file.
This should be of type array by default, if not set it to an array and then add the following items of type "string":

- Item 0: icon.png
- Item 1: icon@2x.png
- Item 2: icon-72.png

Optionally you can add the iPad retina one as well (if you are using that icon, if not I'd omit it):

- Item 3: icon-72@2x.png

After doing that the error went away and I was able to archive/validate/submit my app to the app store with xCode without a problem.